# How to get the incoming call phone number?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I want to get incoming phone number in android. I have tried using BroadcastListenerand my Broadcastlistener looks like this..

```
    public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
            public int cnt = 0;
public int cnt2 = 0;
TelephonyManager telephony;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if(telephony != null)return;
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String state1 = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state1.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) && state == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing - " + cnt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cnt++;
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : " + cnt + " " + incomingNumber);

            }

        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

    }
```

This provide the number correctly but the problem is when any new call is ringing the previous numbers always shown in toast. For example, if three call come one after another, on third time there will be 3 toast message. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think you're mixing two different methods of getting updates on call state changes: `BroadcastReceiver` & `PhoneStateListener`.

You should use either the first one, or the second one.
By Using both, you actually keep registering more and more listeners for the same event, so you end up after 3 calls with 3 listeners that basically do the same.

If you want to use the listener approach with `PhoneStateListener`, simply register your listener when your app launches and handle the incoming events once.

Remove the broadcast receiver registration code and from your manifest.